# JQuery Mobile Select Menu in a pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I would like to ask some question regarding a select menu pop up. I want to make a a pop up with select menu.

I have #popupMenu2 link. After I click on the link, a popupMenu2 div will show up with its list of UL like 'Delete Data'. Then, After I click on the 'Delete Data', It will show up another pop up which contains selection menu of multi data. User can select many of them (Data 1, Data 2,..etc).

My code does not work what it is supposed to be.
The following is my code snippet. 
Your help is very important to me.

Best Regards,

HTML:

```
<a id="moreoption" href="#popupMenu2" style="float: right;margin-right: 11px;display: block;right: 25px;" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b">More Options...</a>
<!--  -->
<div id="popupMenu2" data-role="popup" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;">
<ul id="mainmenu" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;" data-theme="d">
  <li data-role="divider" data-theme="e">Choose an action</li>
  <li>
     <a href="#popupmultimenu" data-role="popup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-theme="a">Delete Data</a>
     <div data-role="popup" id="popupmultimenu" data-theme="a">
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
           <select name="select-custom-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
              <option>Choose options</option>
              <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
              <option value="2" selected="selected">The 2nd Option</option>
              <option value="3" selected="selected">The 3rd Option</option>
              <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
           </select>
        </div>
     </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">View Details</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">View Report</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Others</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't just talk about your code. Include snippets in the question.

Comment: This is more like a question about usability and design - You may: 1) rethink the flow of your application, 2) use a nested menu or 3)if you absolutely stay on popups, here is a post of  [ezanker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1098622/ezanker): [Chained Popups With SimpleDialog2](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/chained-popups-with-simpledialog2/)

Comment: Thank you. Yes. It is dealing with the flow of the application. Now I can fix the issue. Thank you. Regards